# Mongodb sort case insensitive for lookup function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

below code is how i do sorting for my lookup function:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'members',
        let: { abc: '$abc' },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$abc'] } }
            },
            { $sort: { name: 1 } }
        ],
        as: 'cde'
    }
}
```

Now I want to make the sort to be case insensitive. I know that normally we can use `collation: { locale: 'en' }`. But how to add this into the lookup function?